# Nodes without addresses

Tags: overpass-api

I have searched for a while, but have not found a suitable answer yet.
I have the following problem. When I execute the following query [[1]](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Orh) via the overpass API, I get nodes as a result that don't have an address. 
My question: Is it possible to query the address somehow too?

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 271449962,
  "lat": 50.7261247,
  "lon": 7.1242361,
  "tags": {
    "amenity": "biergarten",
    "name": "Zum Blauen Affen",
    "wheelchair": "limited"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "query the address" you mean things like city, zip code, country and so forth.

Overpass API is not a geocoder, and therefore isn't really a good fit for those kind of requests. You can however use the Overpass API result, and process it via a Geocoder (such as Nominatim) in a second step.